# pyparsing recursive does not throw exception

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have the following snippet with recursive statement from a pyparsing parser:

```
def parse_query(querystr):
    # <<other parsing stuff>>
    queryexpression = querycondition + ZeroOrMore(Word("and") + querycondition)
    try:
        return queryexpression.parseString(querystr)
    except ParseException as e:
        logger.debug("Error parsing '{0}': \n {1}".format(querystr, e))
        return None
```

when I feed this the query:

```
tokens = parse_query("HR:EE > -28.9 and BL:AA = 0 THISISNOTAND KLAS:TT eq true")
print(tokens)
```

it yields:

```
[['HR', ':', 'EE', '>', '-28.9'], 'and', ['BL', ':', 'AA', '=', '0']]
```

and just silently skips the last condition. No Exception thrown.

How do I catch the error in this string?

Comment: I don't see the part where anything recursive happens.

Comment: queryexpression = querycondition + ZeroOrMore(Word("and") + querycondition)

Comment: That's not recursion, that's just using the same nonterminal twice in one production.

Comment: `ZeroOrMore` implies iteration, not recursion. Neither reference to `querycondition` in `queryexpression` is recursive, unless a `querycondition` can (possibly indirectly) contain a `queryexpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> queryexpression = querycondition + ZeroOrMore(Word("and") + querycondition)

This is *not required to parse the entire line*. `ZeroOrMore` means exactly that. It stops when it encounters something that fails to meet the definition. It will always succeed, because "zero" is a valid option for the number of times that the nested expression is matched.

If you want to parse all the way to the end of a line, then you will need an expression that explicitly requires that, for example by tacking on `+ LineEnd`.

Lines are not "special" unless you make them so. A parsing expression, by default, expects to match a prefix of the input, not the entire input, because you always might want to use another expression to parse the next bit.

Comment: `StringEnd` is what I would suggest, as opposed to `LineEnd`.  You can also accomplish this by adding `parseAll=True` argument to `parseString`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire assuming that the text is being fed to the parser a line at a time, sure. Although I would assume that's the case given the OP's apparent expectations... Thanks for pointing out the `parseAll` argument, too. - Hey, wait, aren't you the **author** of pyparsing? :)